# Determine general solution for Gompertz differentialequation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Gompertz equation $P(t):$

$\frac{dP}{dt} = cP  ln(\frac{K}{P})$

where c is a parameter and $∀t≥0 : P(t)≤K$

I'm supposed to determine the general solution and limit when t approaches infinity.

First I wrote the equation as:

$\frac{dP}{(cP ln(\frac{K}{P})} = dt$

Then I tried integrating by substitution and got:

$-\frac{ln(ln(\frac{K}{P})}{c}= dt$

Which is wrong according to a friend but he didn't give any specifics

Comment: This is a separable equation, what is the problem?

Comment: @Did Well I wrote it as $\frac{dp}{(cP ln(\frac{K}{P})} = dt$ which by substitution  I got to be $- \frac{ln(ln\frac{k}{p}}{c} = dt$ , friend told me it isn't correct so not really sure what I'm supposed to do/or what I did wrong

Comment: Explain your solution in details in your question, possibly also add the nature of your friend's objections (but be specific), and then we will have a question suitable for the site (at present we have none) and people will be willing to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

To get rid of the logarithm, start using
$$\log \left(\frac{k}{P}\right)=u\implies P=k\, e^{-u}\implies P'=-k\, e^{-u}\,u'$$ So
$$P'=c P \log \left(\frac{k}{P}\right)\implies e^{-u}(cu+u')=0\implies cu+u'=0$$ which looks to be quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

solving the equation
$$\frac{dP}{cP\ln\left(\frac{K}{P}\right)}=dt$$ we get
$$P \left( t \right) =K{{\rm e}^{-{{\rm e}^{-{\it \_C}\,c-tc}}}}$$
we have used $$\frac{1}{c}\int\frac{1}{x\log\left(\frac{K}{x}\right)}dx=\frac{1}{c}\left(-\log \left(\log \left(\frac{K}{x}\right)\right)\right)$$

Comment: I have no clue how you got to that answer

Comment: i have added the integral for you!

Comment: Ah I got: $-\frac{ln(ln(\frac{K}{P})}{c}$ what happened to your $c$?

Comment: $c$ is assumed to be a constant, we do not Need it for the integral

Comment: So would the RHS be the general solution and I follow how we integrated but I don't understand how you get $P(t)$ from that. Tips on how I should substitute $t$ when I try the limit approaching infinity later?